# JavaScript form value with variable field name

Tags: javascript

simple javascript but can't seem to get it to work.

```
var number = 5;
var netiteration = "net"+number;  // makes netiteration now equal net5

var formvalue = document.forms.myformname.netiteration.value;
```

why doesn't this get the value of the form field with the name/id of "net5", in the form "myformname"?

also, I'm working from a 10 year old javascript book, so maybe the syntax has changed?

thanks

Comment: did you try `document.getElementsByName(netiteration)[0].value`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
var number = 5;
var netiteration = "net"+number;  // makes netiteration now equal net5

var formvalue = document.forms.myformname[netiteration].value;
```

Your original code was looking for a field called "netiteration" but you want the field that has a name equal to the evaluated value of netiteration.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as netiteration is a variable and you cannot use variable name within the DOM structure of the HTML.

something like following should work....

```
var form_elements = document.forms.myformname.getAllChildren();
var net_elements = new Array[10];
for(var i=0;i<form_elements.length;i++)
{
   var name = form_elements[i].name;
   if(name.indexOf('net') != -1)
    net_elements[i] = form_elements[i];
}
```

now, the arraynet_elements has all the elements with the name 'net' in it...

hopes this solves your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Came across this and thought I'd enhance it with some extra info in case someone finds it useful.

If you are using id in your form fields, you can reference that way also:

```
<input type='text' id='myfield1' onclick="Example(1)">
<input type='text' id='myfield2' onclick="Example(2)">
```

then in your Javascript you reference the field with a variable by:

```
function Example(myvar){
    var myvalue=document.getElementById('myfield'+myvar);   
    console.log('The value is '+myvalue);
}
```